# Streaming Results and res.render nodejs

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, express

I am using express and mysql-native with nodejs. With the mysql-native I stream results from the db row by row like this (in coffee):

```
exports.getUser = (username,callback) ->
 query = mysql.query "select * from users where username = #{username}"
 query.on "row", (row)->
  callback row
```

(obviously I would use prepared statements this is an example)

This sort of method won't work with res.render because you cannot be calling the res.render multiple times every time you get a new row

```
database.getUser "username", (result)->
  res.render "people", "data" : result
```

Is there some other method for sending streamed data or would I have to stream results to the view with sockets?

Comment: How do you intend to render the view progressively? That's not even feasible in most template engines.

Comment: I don't care how it is rendered I just dont want to get into sockets. If I could avoid it I would be pleased

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out last night in a moment of inspiration since I am streaming the data I can listen for when the stream ends and run my callback. That way I can push the data to an array then use in on a callback like so:

```
 query = mysql.query "select * from users where id = 2"
 data = []
 query.on "row", (row)->
   data.push row
 query.on "end", ()->
   callback data
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was talking about. You can't "stream" a view (in normal circumstances). You need all the data first before you can render it.

Comment: Well yes your comment was very helpful. It made me think of a different way instead of streaming the result. but would you consider this a best practice?

Comment: It's fine. Usually a simple async driver is enough, unless you're doing computation/transformations on large data sets, then streaming gives you huge performance benefits.

Answer (score 0):

you can use your preferred templating engine directly

```
var row = _.template('<tr><td> <%= id > </td> </tr>');
...
database.getUser "username", (result)->
  res.write( row(result) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [Express partials](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#view-partials).